.Net Entity Framework. Updating ICollection of an object
I've searched for resolution on similar problems and I made some progress but I got stuck to the poin I can't progress.
I'm woring on a practie project where I can update the member of the app details.
I use EntityFramework to write to sql database but I have a problem with updatting properties of the memebr which are IColection
member object:
{
 Some properties: string.....
 ICollection<Interest> Interest
}

When I send and object from my frontend I send the entire Mmeber. The change that I'm trying to save is newly added item to a Interest Collection.
My Endpoint:
[HttpPut]
    public async Task<ActionResult> UpdateMember(MemberDto member)
    {   
        if (this.HttpContext.Request.Cookies.ContainsKey("access-token"))
            {
                var cookieValue = this.HttpContext.Request.Cookies["access-token"];
                var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
                var token = tokenHandler.ReadJwtToken(cookieValue);
                var userName = token
                    .Claims.FirstOrDefault(claim =>
                        claim.Type == JwtRegisteredClaimNames.UniqueName
                    ).Value;
                var user = await this.userRepository.GetUserByUsernameAsync(userName.ToString());
                if (user == null) return NotFound();

                this.context.Entry(user).State = EntityState.Detached;
                var updatedUser = this.mapper.Map(member, user);
                
                this.context.Entry(user).State = EntityState.Modified;

                this.userRepository.Update(user, updatedUser);
                if (await this.userRepository.SaveAllAsync()) return NoContent();
                return BadRequest("Failed to update user");
            }
        return BadRequest("User nor recognised");
    }

My Repository handling updating and saving:
public async Task<bool> SaveAllAsync()
        {
            return await context.SaveChangesAsync() > 0;
        }

        public void Update(AppUser user, AppUser updatedUser)
        {
            context.Entry(user).CurrentValues.SetValues(updatedUser);

            UpdateCollection<Interest>(user.Interests, updatedUser.Interests);

        }

        private void UpdateCollection<T>(ICollection<T> existingCollection, ICollection<T> updatedCollection) where T : class
        {
            var existingItems = existingCollection.ToList();
            var updatedItems = updatedCollection.ToList();

            foreach(var updatedItem in updatedItems)
            {
                if(!existingItems.Contains(updatedItem))
                {
                    existingCollection.Add(updatedItem);
                    context.Entry(updatedItem).State = EntityState.Added;
                }
            }

            foreach(var existingItem in existingItems)
            {
                if(!updatedItems.Contains(existingItem))
                {
                    existingCollection.Remove(existingItem);
                    context.Entry(existingItem).State = EntityState.Deleted;
                }
            }

            
        }

I'm using Scopped service for the context.
As well I'm using AutoMapper:
CreateMap<MemberDto, AppUser>()
                .ForMember(dest => dest.Interests, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Interests))
                .ForMember(dest => dest.Photos, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Photos))
                .ForMember(dest => dest.Languages, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Languages))
                .ForMember(dest => dest.Settings, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Settings));
            
            CreateMap<PhotoDto, Photo>();
            CreateMap<LanguageDto, Language>();
            CreateMap<InterestDto, Interest>();
            CreateMap<UserSettingDto, UserSetting>();

I'm still learning and I've tried to debug it. I can see that when the memberDTO have 5 object in Interest propertie and the User retrieved from Context have 4 but then when I loop through Existing properties the user Interests have already 5 objects. I do not get any errors but then when I retrieve back the same user the data Interest property have 4 objects. It seems like the changes are not saving themselfs.
Apreciate any help
After all of the above code I would expect that the ICollection is getting updated with the new interest.

From my understanding AutoMapper should automatically detect the change so I shouldn't even need to use UpdateCollection.

Automapper don't know anything about EF and which PrimaryKey is used for mapping betweeb DTO and Entity. What should help is AutoMapper.Collection

Also you can find useful universal function for that MergeCollections

Ok, for a start you are doing way, way too much work... It's confusing to read what you are ripping away from EF and then trying to hand back. For a start, code like setting the EntityState is not a normal thing, a simple update scenario should not involve it. The same goes for using Update(). This is provided for situations where you are working with detached entities. You have no reason to need to work with detached entities since you are loading entities on the spot.
The first step is to simplify your code considerably. Ignore the urge to introduce a Repository here, you don't need it. EF already provides a repository via the DbSet<T>, start there.
So you have a DTO coming in for the updated user and I'm assuming it has Interests information as well. Without seeing the DTO, I would suggest that all the DTO needs to include for Interest information is a collection of InterestIds.  We don't need Automapper to convert the DTO and interests into an entity object. That can be useful for Insert scenarios, but I would avoid it on Updates. The reason I would avoid it for updates is that the DTO should only pass details that we want to allow to be changed. This can mean that we don't have enough info to accurately compose a complete User, nor should we try to pass enough from a Client to compose a complete User. That information could be tampered with causing us to overwrite details that a client has no business changing. If a client can update 3 columns then the DTO should provide the UserId and those 3 columns. (Our server call should verify the UserId is a valid user for this client session to be updating)
Next, performing an update. When updating an entity that has a collection of related data it is important to fetch that related data. This means eager loading the Insterests with the User:
[HttpPut]
public async Task<ActionResult> UpdateMember(MemberDto member)
{
    try
    {
        var userName = getCurrentUserName();
        
        var user = await _context.Users
            .Include(user => user.Interests)
            .SingleOrDefaultAsync(user => user.UserName == userName);
        if (user == null) 
            return NotFound();

        // TODO: Check that current user can alter user passed in member? 
        // (either that member is same user, or an authorization check?)

        // TODO: copy values from DTO to user....

        // Update the Interest references.
        var existingInterestIds = user.Interests.Select(i => i.InterestId).ToList();
        var updatedInterestIds = member.InterestIds;
        var interestIdsToAdd = updatedInterestIds.Except(existingInterestIds);
        var interestIdsToRemove = existingInterestIds.Except(updatedInterestIds);

        if(interestIdsToRemove.Any())
        {
            var interestsToRemove = user.Interests.Where(i => interestIdsToRemove.Contains(i.InterestId));
            foreach(var interest in interestsToRemove)
                user.Interests.Remove(interest);
        }
        if(interestIdsToAdd.Any())
        {
            var interestsToAdd = await _context.Interests
                .Where(i => interestIdsToAdd.Contains(i.InterestId))
                .ToListAsync();
            foreach(var interest in interestsToAdd)
                user.Interests.Add(interest); 
        }

        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

        return NoContent();
    }
    catch(UnauthorizedAccessException)
    {
        return Unauthorized();
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        // TODO: Log exception
        return BadRequest();
    }
}

private string getCurrentUserName()
{
    if (!HttpContext.Request.Cookies.ContainsKey("access-token"))
        throw new UnauthorizedAccessException("No user session.");

    var cookieValue = this.HttpContext.Request.Cookies["access-token"];
    var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
    var token = tokenHandler.ReadJwtToken(cookieValue);
    var userName = token.Claims
        .FirstOrDefault(claim => claim.Type == JwtRegisteredClaimNames.UniqueName)
        .Value;

   if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(userName))
        throw new UnauthorizedAccessException("No user session.");

   return userName;
}

Here I've extracted the logic to get the current user session, this is probably something that is going to be done a bit so it can be moved down to a base-class controller method or the like. When we fetch the User to be updated, we eager-load the Interests using .Include(user => user.Interests). From here since I assume we are dealing with associations of users and interests we find what interests might have been added or removed. We then remove any interests that aren't in the updated list, and for any interests to  be added, we fetch those from the DbContext and associate them to the user. Once that is done we just call SaveChanges as EF is tracking all changes to the user and associated collections by default.
For copying the user details that can be changed you can do that either manually field by field or you can set up Automapper to copy values from the DTO to the User entity and use the Mapper.Map(src, dest) method you were using. I typically recommend using manual copying or a parameterized DDD-style method as it's easy to read and understand what should, be copied across, especially if you are investigating problems and Find Usages on a property setter. Mappers are useful but can be a bit of a black box concealing bugs.

Thanks for quick reply. I'm following the course from udemy however I'm adding to it more complicated data and additional features. I managed to fix this by using AutoMapper.Collections. Thank you for suggestions to separating extracting the user from the endpoint. AutoMapper have problems on it's own when it comes to nested collections in the object. As well this code is only for updates of the currently logged in user I will be adding this feature as well for the admin so at the later stage I will be adding logic for checking the permissions. It's my first post but Love the website and help
